# Linkage Error occurred while loading main class Try running with '--enable-preview'

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar

I have issue  with jar file . When ever I want to open it I have to write java --enable-preview -jar .jar.

I'm using Java 16.0.1

I'm not using Maven or anything else. I just created my java project in Visual Studio Code. I even tried javac -cp --enable-preview --release 16 src\filename.java src\packs*.java -d bin

to auto enable it at compile time.

Still it is showing : Linkage Error occurred while loading main class : Preview features are not enabled for  (class file version 60.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'.

Please Help me in this scenario. I cannot share my code as it is of more than 3.5 k lines

Comment: I also want to create a .exe file from the jar file but as the jar file wont run directly without any command the exe file wont run too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO basically I had to create a .bat file with `java --enable-preview -jar <filename>.jar`

this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In [Enabling Java preview features](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Enabling-Java-preview-features), it says projects need to be updated to use Java 16 in vscode-java. so in Settings.json, set

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-16",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-16",
    "default": true
  },
],
```

Open command palette and select **Java: Export Jar**. Try to export jar by the command provided by java extension and see if your question goes away.

Comment: I have tried this but it is still showing the same error I have also tried adding "vmArgs": "--enable-preview" in Launch.json file. Still when I run the jar file i get the following error    .  Also After the adding the above code in Setting file it is not highlighted it is unused . Can you please help

Comment: @BHGROUP. umm...then you may ask in [github-vscode-java](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues) for more help.

Comment: @BHGROUP. Don't forget to share the solution here if your question is solved :)

Comment: Sure , Will do once I get the solution